# jQuery How To Add Form Validation Using 5-step Sliding Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm a newbie and find very difficult to read and understand complex javascript from other's work.

I would like to ask some help in making a simplified jquery for me to use rather than using the complex code which I don't really understand.

First: this is a 5 step form consist of gender, first name, dob, email and password. There are validations in every steps.

See the complex code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var Fist = {
    config: {
    stepsSelector: $(".steps"),
    nextSelector: $(".myButton"),
    errorSelector: $(".error"),
    indSelector: $(".steps-ind"),
    form: "",
    cur_step: 1,
    max_step: 1,
    offset: 278,
    errorString: "This field is required",
    clickEvent: "touchstart"
},

    run: function(e) {
        this.config.form = e;
        var t = this;
        var n = $(".regform").width();
        t.config.offset = n;
        if (typeof document.body.ontouchstart === "undefined") {
            t.config.clickEvent = "click"
        }
        t.config.indSelector.find(".step-ind" + t.config.cur_step).addClass("step-ind-active");
        t.config.nextSelector.on(t.config.clickEvent, function() {
            t.process()
        });
        t.config.form.find("input").on("keypress", function(e) {
            var n = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
            if (n === 13) {
                t.process()
            }
        });
        t.config.indSelector.find("div").on(t.config.clickEvent, function() {
            t.gotoStep($(this))
        })
    },

    indicateStep: function(e) {
        var t = this;
        t.config.indSelector.find("div").removeClass("step-ind-active");
        t.config.indSelector.find(".step-ind" + e).addClass("step-ind-active");
        setTimeout(function() { $('.step'+e+' input, .step'+e+' select').focus() }, 500);
    },

    animateStep: function(e) {
        var t = this;
        t.config.stepsSelector.css({
            transform: "translateX(-" + (e - 1) * t.config.offset + "px)"
        }, function() {
            t.config.form.find(".step" + e).find("input").focus()
        })
    },

    process: function() {
        var e = this;
        var t = e.config.form.find(".step" + e.config.cur_step).find("input,select");
        var n = false;
        t.each(function() {
            if (!e.validate($(this))) {
            n = true
            }
        });

        if (!n) {
            e.config.cur_step++;
            if (e.config.cur_step === 6) {
                e.config.form.submit()
            } else {
                e.config.max_step = e.config.cur_step;
                e.animateStep(e.config.cur_step);
                e.indicateStep(e.config.cur_step);
                if (e.config.cur_step === 5) {
                    e.config.nextSelector.val("Submit")
                }
            }
        }
    },

    gotoStep: function(e) {
        var t = e.text();
        var n = this;
        if (t < n.config.max_step) {
            n.animateStep(t);
            n.indicateStep(t);
            n.config.cur_step = t;
            if (t === 5) {
                n.config.nextSelector.val("Submit")
            } else {
                n.config.nextSelector.val("Next")
            }
        } else {
            n.process()
        }
    },

    validate: function(e) {
        var t = this;
        t.config.errorSelector.hide();
        e.removeClass("error-item");
        var n = false;
        if ($.trim(e.val()) === "") {
            n = true;
            t.config.errorString = "This field is required"
        }

        if (e.attr("name") === "email" && !t.validateEmail(e.val())) {
            n = true;
            t.config.errorString = "Invalid email address"
        }

        if (e.attr("name") === "firstname" && !t.validateName(e.val())) {
            n = true;
            t.config.errorString = "Invalid name"
        }

        if (n) {
            t.config.errorSelector.empty().append(t.config.errorString).fadeIn("fast");
            e.addClass("error-item");
            return false
        }
        return true
    },

    validateEmail: function(e) {
        var t = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return t.test(e)
    },

    validateInt: function(e) {
        var t = /^\d{1,}$/;
        return t.test(e)
    },

    validateName: function(e) {
        var t = /^\w+(\s)?\w+(\s)?(\w+)?$/;
        return t.test(e)
    }
}
Fist.run($("#regform"));
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="regform">
<div class="form-wrapper">
    <form id="regform" method="post" action="http://www.test.com/signup">
        <div class="steps step1">
            <label>Your Gender?</label>
            <div name="gender">
                <div class="man-btn color" value="1">
                    <span>Man</span>
                    <div class="man" >
                        <i class="fa fa-male" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="woman-btn" value="2">
                    <span>Woman</span>
                    <div class="woman">
                        <i class="fa fa-female" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="steps step2">
            <label>First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstname">
        </div>
        <div class="steps step3">
            <label>What is Your Date of Birth?</label>
            <select name="dobday" id="dobday" class="required">
                <option value="">Day</option>
                <option value="1">01</option>
                <option value="2">02</option>
                <option value="3">03</option>
                <option value="4">04</option>
                <option value="5">05</option>
                <option value="6">06</option>
                <option value="7">07</option>
                <option value="8">08</option>
                <option value="9">09</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="16">16</option>
                <option value="17">17</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
                <option value="19">19</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="21">21</option>
                <option value="22">22</option>
                <option value="23">23</option>
                <option value="24">24</option>
                <option value="25">25</option>
                <option value="26">26</option>
                <option value="27">27</option>
                <option value="28">28</option>
                <option value="29">29</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option value="31">31</option>
            </select>
            <select name="dobmonth" id="dobmonth" class="required">
                <option value="">Month</option>
                <option value="1">January</option>
                <option value="2">February</option>
                <option value="3">March</option>
                <option value="4">April</option>
                <option value="5">May</option>
                <option value="6">June</option>
                <option value="7">July</option>
                <option value="8">August</option>
                <option value="9">September</option>
                <option value="10">October</option>
                <option value="11">November</option>
                <option value="12">December</option>
            </select>
            <select name="dobyear" id="dobyear" class="required">
                <option value="">Year</option>
                <?php for($x=date("Y") - 18; $x >= 1918; $x--): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $x; ?>"><?php echo $x; ?></option>
                <?php endfor; ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="steps step4">
            <label>Email:</label>
            <input type="email" pattern="[^ @]*@[^ @]*" name="email">
        </div>
        <div class="steps step5">
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password">
        </div>
        <div class="error">This field is required</div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="submit">
    <input type="button" class="myButton" value="Next">
</div>
<div class="steps-ind">
    <div class="step-ind1">1</div>
    <div class="step-ind2">2</div>
    <div class="step-ind3">3</div>
    <div class="step-ind4">4</div>
    <div class="step-ind5">5</div>
</div>
```

Please help me. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Have you tried simplifying it down yourself already? :)

Comment: @AliceYu i've seen of samples but most of it are different forms.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this form? If you're looking for something this intricate with validation built in already, then this is perfect for you already.

Comment: @AliceYu yeah but i'm trying to insert new things esp on gender. They are not select type. They are somewhat buttons now.

Comment: I put a little example in the answers that might help :) It's just adding a new div based on the existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple enough to add a new button! You could either change the gender to a select dropdown or you could add a new `div` like this:

```
            <div class="bro-btn" value="3">
                <span>Bro</span>
                <div class="bro">
                    <i class="fa fa-bro" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Few things you have to note: The `fa fa-bro` is a reference to a class in your CSS that adds an icon corresponding to whatever gender is selected. If you were to add new buttons like above, you would have to find an icon that matches from [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io).